# extract single label as column in log panel

Tags: grafana-loki

I've just started exploring Loki to aggregate my logs and I'm assuming I've missed something obvious.

I have a bunch of machines/vms/containers with promtail forwarding systemd's journal to a single loki server (just the default example config) and I can explore them just fine. I can filter the logs by any of the labels as required.

However, on a dashboard panel I have tried both the "table" and "logs" panel types and can't seem to do what seems extremely basic to me. I want filter by some of my labels and then extract one or more of the remaining labels as a column to be displayed. The closest I have found is to turn on "Unique labels" in the "logs" panel type which just throws all of the values in one column together.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the table panel type. Then go to the `Transform` tab which is located next to the `Query` tab at the bottom. Add an `Extract fields` transformation and for the `Source` dropdown select `Labels`. Then press `Add path` button and enter the name of the label you want as a column.

Note that there is also an `Organize Fields` transform which is useful to control the visibility and ordering of columns.

Comment: Thanks very much - this seemed to be exactly what I was after.

Comment: This only works if the logs are JSON-formatted or have key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Just starting out also, so please don't take this as authoritative.

I made some progress by:

1. processing the log "Line" using a [regexp](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#regular-expression) to create capture groups as referable labels, and
2. using the [line_format](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-format-expression) to re-assemble the log line in the desired format

   ... | regexp `^(?P<thread><.*>)\s+(?P<channel>\[.*\])\s+(?P<message>.*)$` | line_format "{{.env}} {{.node}} {{.thread}} {{.channel}} {{.message}}"

Hope it helps.

Update:

You can also prepend information using the `template` stage when sending, something like as follows (in the agent config):

```
- template:                  
    source: message                  
    template: '{{ .node }} {{ .message }}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that's mangling the log-line itself though, which wasn't what I was after. I suppose I could keep the original line after the newly regexp-extracted repetition of the label.

Comment: You can also mangle it at the sender (updated answer), but I agree that both feel a bit hacky

Comment: While I can get labels/fields I want in the data by configuring `promtail` with a regex, I'm still confused about the (non-)possibilities to have **columns** in a **logs panel**, i.e. some *table* functionality in a *logs panel*. It seems, surprisingly, that there is no solution for that yet? (https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/42315)

Answer (score 2):

Use [line_format](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-format-expression) and the [line](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#__line__) function in the following form:

```
... | line_format "{{(printf \"%-7s\" .node)}} {{__line__}}"
```

assuming that `node` is the label, and you want those printf format specifiers (adjust to taste).

`line_format` allows any go template argument, so should be able to achieve the need I think.

Note: for performance reasons it is preferred to put such processing after any filtering steps.